# Getting and comparing the value of <select>

Tags: php

I'm making for a log-in for the system we're developing. The problem is, I have 3 main entities but only a single log-in form.

The log in logic goes like this:
If the user is an administrator, he will be redirected to adminpanel.php,
client.php for client and
employee.php for employee.

So how would I get this done? I want the program to identify whether the user is an admin, a client or an employee.

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert ('Log In Successful!')";;

    if($_GET['type']==Client){  
        echo "window.location.href='client.php'";
    }
    elseif($_GET['type']==Employee){    
        echo "window.location.href='employee.php'";
    } else {
        echo "window.location.href='adminpanel.php'";
    }
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far?

Comment: And which framework (if you use some) are you using? If not, post your code too.

Comment: come on man. we don't have any magic. please show code you have tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want help from guys here, answer this question first : [what have i tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Use " " or ' ' for string. But using PHP into JavaScript like redirect is ugly.

Comment: Indenting works exactly the other way round from what you're doing. after a `{` indent goes right, after a `}` ident goes left.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a user to the database, save their user type.

Then when they log in, fetch the user using their username and/or password.

Check the type. Serve the page depending on type (using a switch statement or if statements).

To be honest, you'd be better of using a Framework. CodeIgniter is good for beginners.

Google CodeIgniter and work through the tutorials and examples...

Comment: I do have field for account type in my database. The problem is I don't know how to get this part right.

Comment: If you have the field in the database, why can't you just check what type it is, and then serve the page depending on that?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, but is my code above correct? It displays a blank page for me.

Comment: You should do it serverside, and then include the php file. There is no need to redirect. there is no need for javascript